# Auto wrap inline math mode

Tags: math-mode, geometry

I have this situation:

[image]

How you can see, the two math string exceed the page geometry. The document class that I use is `MastersDoctoralThesis` and it is available [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis).

There is a method to **auto-wrap** the inline math? Or something that prevent this problem?

This is the portion of text that contains the math text:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Un vettore $\mathcal{F}$ di dimensione $\sigma = |\Sigma|$ nel quale salvare le frequenze cumulative degli ultimi caratteri delle etichette dei nodi. 
        Ovvero, $\mathcal{F}[c] = |\Set{i | 1 \leq i \leq m, C(i) < c}|$, dove $C(i)$ indica
        l'ultimo carattere di $Node[i]$. Viene rappresentato con $\mathcal{O}(\sigma\log m)$ bits.
\end{enumerate}
```

## Update

Another example of math text that exceed the geometry:

[image]

The text is:

```
Un \textbf{suffix array}~\cite{doi:10.1137/0222058}, ($SA_X$), è 
una rappresentazione
succinta dell'ordinamento lessicografico di tutti i suffissi di una strina $X$.
Più precisamente, $SA_X$ è un array $SA[1\dots n]$ che contiene tutte le permutazioni
degli interi $[1\dots n]$ tale che $X[SA[1]\dots n] \prec X[SA[2]\dots n] \prec 
\dots \prec X[SA[n]\dots n]$.
```

I also try to `wrap` for example `SA` with `\text{}` but the problem persists.

This is the full paragraph:
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the part of the code which corresponds to what is on the screenshot?

Comment: @Enevevet I just update my question :)

Comment: Please add the `\Set` definition if you created it or the package it comes from if you didn't.

Comment: @Enevevet The `\Set` definition is in the `braket` package

Comment: Could you please include the essential packages to reproduce the problem with a complete minimal working example? I am agree totally with @Enevevet. The information are very small "Io scrivo malissimo in inglese" :-( What are the margins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `braket` package, `\Set` is defined as following:

```latex
\xdef\Set{\protect\expandafter\noexpand\csname Set \endcsname}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname Set \endcsname#1{\left\{%
     \ifx\SavedDoubleVert\relax \let\SavedDoubleVert\|\fi
     \:{\let\|\SetDoubleVert
     \mathcode`\|32768\let|\SetVert
     #1}\:\right\}}
```

I think the `\left` and `right` are preventing line breaks. You can choose between redefining the `\Set` command or defining a **bis** command in case you need it to be able to break the line. Also I think the `\Set` expanded the box which led the `\mathcal{O}(\sigma\log m)` to exceed too.

Anyway I would define it as following:

```latex
\newcommand{\Setbis}[2]{\{#1 \mid #2 \,\}}

...

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Un vettore $\mathcal{F}$ di dimensione $\sigma = |\Sigma|$ nel quale salvare le frequenze cumulative degli ultimi caratteri delle etichette dei nodi. 
        Ovvero, $\mathcal{F}[c] = |\Setbis{i}{1 \leq i \leq m, C(i) < c}|$, dove $C(i)$ indica
        l'ultimo carattere di $\text{Node}[i]$. Viene rappresentato con $\mathcal{O}(\sigma\log m)$ bits.
\end{enumerate}
```

And here's the output:

[image: LaTeX output updated]

**Edit:** As @Sebastiano pointed out in the comments, it may be better to use `$\text{Node}[i]$` instead of `$Node[i]$`. I updated my code and the output according to this.

Comment: Excellent. I suggest to put, differently of the user, $\text{Node}[i]$ instead of $Node[i]$. Please can you put a MWE?

Comment: I update my question with another example where I don't use any `braket` or other package. It's only pure math text.

Comment: No that is not what `\text` is for, if the surrounding text is in, say, italics, then Node is in italics. Use `\mathrm{Node}` or even `\operatorname{Node}`

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man Could you please provide a screenshot of the whole paragraph so I can see how the citation is formatted? I was unable to reproduce the problem for now.

Comment: @Enevevet Of course, I edit the question :)